# Expected behaviour for update.packages after R version upgrade under Windows XP?

Tags: r, windows-xp, package

I've just updated R from 2.15.2 to 3.0.2., and as part of that, as recommended in the R for Windows FAQ, I've copied my packages to the new lib directory, and run update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE).  I selected my local CRAN repository, and a number of packages were listed as being updated, on the console, also the message:

> The downloaded binary packages are in
>           C:\Documents and Settings\MyName\Local Settings\Temp\Rtmp8mncq4\downloaded_packages

Does this mean they are actually installed in R?  Can these temp files be deleted?  Or do I need to do something else in order to activate it?  (This is my first R upgrade and package upgrade, and I'm not sure whether this is as it should be.)

If there is somewhere else I should be asking this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temp files can be deleted. They probably will be in due course anyway. If you didn't get any errors or warning messages about not being able to install then your updates were all successful.